# How to call function from another file in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have this function in a javascript-file:

```
//utils/commons.js

export function funcName() {
    return 1;
}
```

In a component I refer to it this way:

```
import React from 'react';
const funcName  = import('../../utils/commons');

const MyComponent = () => {
    let res = funcName();
    console.log('res:',res);

    return(
        <> 
        <div>
            hello
        </div>   
    )};
export default MyComponent;
```

This seems to be the right way when googling this matter. However, in the console I see:

```
Uncaught TypeError: funcName is not a function
```

If I would write a console.log inside the common.js-file (somewhere outside the function) then it is printed. So the file is getting included. But the function is not recognized for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to edit this :

```
const funcName  = import('../../utils/commons');
```

to this :

```
import { funcName } from '../../utils/commons';
```

Comment: it does thank you, will accept it as soon as they let me do it